# kendo multiselect with maxSelectedItems:1

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I've got a multiselect with maxSelectedItems: 1
Initial value is empty array Array[0]. When I start typing reading is executing successfully. But list with found items not showing.
The problem is kendo thinks that array isn't empty, it's becoming an Array[1] and contains empty string.
I can see it when I set maxSelectedItems to 2.
In select event I see field _old with value [""]. And e.sender._initialValues is also incorrect and contains the same value.
Maybe someone faced the same problem and knows how to fix it?

Or how to override behaviour, which is do not not show autocomplete when selected length = max length. 
But override initial selected value instead?
I've tried to do so in change event:

```
if (self.context.receiver.length > 1) {
     self.context.receiver = self.context.receiver.slice(-1);
     self.$scope.$apply(); 
}
```

but it clears my variable after event handler execution. I've tried with and without apply.

Comment: Can you perhaps recreate this problem in a demo online?

Comment: sorry, i can't. I get data from service and can't share access to it.  But I solved this by setting maxSelectedItems to 2 and slicing values array to 1 item in change method, then calling $scope.$apply().